# How to read word file from server in c# using DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#

How to get a Word file from server in C#? I use following code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Word._Application application = new Word.Application();
        object fileformat = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;
     //  
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"http://www.sample.com/image/");
        foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (file.Extension.ToLower() == ".doc")
            {
                object filename = file.FullName;
                object newfilename = file.FullName.ToLower().Replace(".doc", ".docx");
                Word._Document document = application.Documents.Open(filename);

                document.Convert();
                document.SaveAs(newfilename, fileformat);
                document.Close();
                document = null;
            } 
        }
        application.Quit();
        application = null;
    }
```

but when I use this code to get file from local machine or desktop then work fine.

Please tell me.

Comment: 1. You need to know the path to the folder containing the .doc files.
2. You need to put that path in the new DirectoryInfo([path]) line
3. You then need to compile and deploy the utility to the server. 
4. You should have a folder on your development machine with some doc files for your testing/development phase 5. Since you already had it working with local machine, this is the exact same thing, you'll just end up running the program on the server directly.

Comment: i full fill first two step. bt dnt know about 3 and 4th step please tell me

Comment: Can you edit the question again and put the path that contains your files into the end of the question? i.e., This is my path:  ....

Comment: Compile and deploy just means build the project (CTRL+B) in .net - is this a console app? Then just copy it to the server from your BIN folder...

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `DirectoryInfo` with a URL.

By design, this class only takes a local (or mapped network) path in its constructor.

You need to use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class to get the file from a URL, since it's located on a server on the internet, the only way to retrieve the file is to download it via `HTTP`.

Edit:

Based on your comments, you are looking to process 1 million files on a server you have access to. **There are many ways to handle this.**

You can use a network path to the server, such as

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("\\servername\path\filename.doc")
```

You can just use a local path and create your application as a C# Console Application and use a local path. This is what I call a utility. It would be the faster method since it will process everything locally, and avoid network traffic.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\your-folder\your-doc-file.doc")
```

Since you would run the C# console app directly on the server, the above would work.

Comment: how to use system.net.httpwebrequest any idea?

Comment: i cant download, because i have 1 million file to change into pdf so pleas tell me.

Comment: 1 million files? From a distant URL? Is this URL on a server you control on the same network?

Comment: i want to get file from server change into pdf...and i have 1 million file of word. so please tell me how to get file

Comment: That's a whole project dude. You did not answer my quesiton -- where is this server - is it yours (or your company)? Do you have access directly to the server?

Comment: The code is just an example of how to use DirectoryInfo with a path... since you haven't posted any other code, I suggest to make a new question with more code for what you're trying to do. Your original question was why doesn't DirectoryInfo work with a URL, which we've established that it is not designed to be used with a URL.

Comment: Your code is trying to convert from doc to docx, not pdf. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

DirectoryInfo is just an object that contains information about a directory entry in your file system. It doesn't download a file, which I presume is what you want to do.

The code example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.connection(v=vs.110).aspx is, I think, similar to what you want.

Comment: i want to get file from server change into pdf...and i have 1 million file of word. so please tell me how to get file

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryInfo is for accessing local files or UNC paths. You cannot use it to access a http addressed page. You first need to download the file, i.e. using HttpWebRequest.